# Por que isso não funciona?

Tags: json, ruby

> .rb:2:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   GameSettings.json (Errno::ENOENT)

---

Estou tentando fazer um jogo no `ruby` usando `gosu`, e pra poder alterar o nome do jogo sem precisar alterar todas as variáveis relacionadas a nome no meu código e outras coisas, eu decidi usar `.json`. Eis o código do script `ruby`:

```
require 'gosu'
require 'json'

data_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('GameSettings.json'))

largura = 360
altura = 360
class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
    def initialize(width , height , fullscreen = false)
        super
        self.caption = data_hash['name']
        @message = Gosu::Image.from_text(self, data_hash['Author'], Gosu.default_font_name,30)
    end
    def draw
       @message.draw(10,10,0)
    end
end

window = GameWindow.new(largura, altura, false)
window.show
```

e o do GameSettings.json:

```
{
    "name"  :   "Heart Afeathered",
    "Author"    :   "Davi Martins Guedes",
    "Nacionality"   : "Brazil"
}
```

e quando eu executo vem essa mensagem que eu coloquei no título.

Comment: ah, esqueci de avisar, os dois funcionam separadamente, mas quando eu junto vem essa mensagem de erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo visto o arquivo **GameSettings.json** não está na mesma pasta do arquivo **.rb**. Procure passar o caminho completo para o arquivo, como no exemplo:

```
_ jogo (pasta)
    _ config (pasta)
        GameSettings.json (arquivo)
    Jogo.rb (arquivo)

data_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('config/GameSettings.json'))
```

Além disso, a função **initialize** do objeto **GameWindow** não vai conseguir ler a variável **data_hash**, pois as mesmas estão em um escopos diferentes, portanto é necessário que **data_hash** seja inicializada dentro da função **initialize** de **GameWindow**.

Comment: eles estão na mesma pasta, esqueci de falar isso, mb, mesmo assim, o código que lê o json funciona normalmente, mas quando eu igualo algo dentro da classe GameWindow a um dos data_hash[] dele, o programa simplesmente manda essa mensagem de erro.

Comment: O erro que tá na pergunta lá em cima, é que o ruby não tá achando o arquivo, mas do jeito que você tá falando agora, o problema é outro. O que está acontecendo é que a função **initialize** do objeto **GameWindow**, não consegue enxergar a variável **data_hash**, é uma questão de escopo. O que você tem de fazer é adicionar a declaração de **data_hash** dentro da função **initialize** de **GameWindow**.

Comment: fiz isso e deu certo, muitíssimo obrigado cara^^

Comment: @DaviMartins se a resposta do pedro lhe foi útil, por favor marque-a como aceita clicando no mark no canto superior esquerdo dela - e seja bem vindo ao sopt! :p

Comment: opa, foi mal, ja ia esquecendo